# Is there any way to extract elements from a list which occur twice only? (extracting twins from a list)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

For example lets take a list.

```
lst = [9, 1, 7, 4, 4, 1, 7, 4, 4, 10, 9]
```

I want to extract the elements which occur only twice. The final list should look somewhat like this

```
lst = [9, 1, 7, 4, 4]
```

Comment: More details are needed, 9 and 1 appear only twice but 4 does not - please clarify and show what you have tried already (also, read our [ask] page)

Comment: Is the order important?

Comment: FWIW, you might be able to use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do the counting.

Comment: No the order is not important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
[k for k,v in Counter(lst).items() for n in range(v//2) ]
```

Comment: If you add another `7` to `lst`, this includes it in the output due to `3//2 == 1`. Add a filter: `... if v%2==0 for n in ...`

Comment: true. I guess the original question meant to find as many twins as possible

Comment: @MuhammedShoaib welcome. Please read wjadnrea's comment which may be necessary if you want to exlcude odd-counts of 3,5,7,....

Comment: @BingWang adding another '7' to 'lst' wont include it in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `itertools` and `collection` (Works if the order is not important).

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

lst = [9, 1, 7, 4, 4, 1, 7, 4, 4, 10, 9]

result = list(
    chain(
        *[[key]*(value // 2) 
          for key,value in Counter(sorted(lst)).items()]
        )
    )
```

**Ouptut :**. [1, 4, 4, 7, 9]